# Mac Os Ventura VPN client ignores manually assigned static IP address

Tags: macos, vpn, ventura

I am using Mac Os VPN client to access a L2TP remote server successfully, however what ever my settings, the Mac Os client will negotiate an IP address from the VPN Server DHCP pool, ignoring my settings.
Where am I wrong?
[image]

Comment: I don't think you are wrong. The VPN server can enforce network settings, in particular to enforce no split tunnelling. You need to talk to the manager of the VPN server.

Comment: Not sure about L2TP, but I'm pretty sure in IPSec, the server always assigns the IP address in the remote IP network address pool.